How can I Jest Test an LWC without relying on implementation details and assuming extended HTML does its job?
I have this test:
        it('handles errors from getDummyApiUsers', async () => {
      // Arrange
      const mockError = new Error('Simulated error from getDummyApiUsers');
      getDummyApiUsers.mockRejectedValue(mockError);
      const element = createElement(elementUnderTest, {
        is: DapUserList
      });

      // Act
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      await Promise.resolve();
      return Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                  // Assert
                  const errorElement = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('c-errors'); 
                  expect(errorElement).not.toBeNull(); 
              });
    });

The test is passing.
However, this test does not actually tell me 'Simulated error from getDummyApiUsers' is being displayed.  I know know there is an instance of c-errors, which, if it is doing its job should be displaying 'Simulated error from getDummyApiUsers'.
But what if it stops doing its job?   This won't tell me that.
And, moreove, this test relies on the current implement which uses c-errors, but if the implementation changes, even if 'Simulated error from getDummyApiUsers' is still somehow displayed, I will need to update the test, which may not be desirable (and probably isn't).
Is there a better way to test this so I can know 'Simulated error from getDummyApiUsers' is actually being displayed and not care how it is being displayed?
